# Getting datas on multiple model with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I am getting datas on database with dapper and want to use that values. I am new in ajax so I could not access datas. I dont have any problem in model and controller page. I debugged, it works finely, my problem in ajax. 
Model codes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7PQt.jpg 
Dapper codes in Case.cs file : https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0qRJ.jpg
Controller Codes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlfjj.jpg

I tried like that:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "@Url.Action("Select_Items", "Case")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "bas_trh": bas_trh, "bts_trh": bts_trh}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                alert(value.unvan);
            })
        }
    });
```

When I do debug it is look like that but I could not access vales: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjaQ1.jpg

Comment: please show code instead.. your picture is really low resolution..

Answer (score 0):

you value it seems have three object of array "value (3)". try access it by array id

```
alert(value[0]);
alert(value[1]);
alert(value[2]);
```